# Remove title name from page of apa6 document class

Tags: titles, apa6

In the code below, I wanted to remove the title of the paper "Assignment 1", from the body of the paper in the apa6-document class template (title on page 2 of the document).

Just under the running header of the first page of the body, the section heading ("Introduction"), should appear first.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[man,12pt,floatsintext,longtable,noextraspace,natbib,letterpaper]{apa6}
\usepackage{layouts}

\geometry{reset, letterpaper, height=9in, width=6.1in, hmarginratio=1:1, vmarginratio=1:1, marginparsep=0pt, marginparwidth=0pt, headheight=15pt}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\urlstyle{rm}
\hypersetup{
     colorlinks   = true,
     urlcolor    = black,
     citecolor = black,
}

\title{\vspace{-5.5cm}Assignment 1 \protect\\ Name of Paper\vspace{6.5cm}}
\shorttitle{Short Title of Paper}
\author{by\\Author Name\\EEE XXXX\\Name of Class\vspace{8.7cm}}
\affiliation{Name of University\\ June 5th, 2016}

\setcounter{page}{0}
\abstract{\lipsum[1].}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the option

```
donotrepeattitle
```

to your document class loading:

```
\documentclass[...,donotrepeattitle,...]{apa6}
```